# rudin math analysis - fourier seris, why fourier series is real if and only $c_{-n}=\overline{c_{n}}$

Tags: analysis, proof-verification, fourier-analysis

In the *principles of Mathematical Analysis*, here is the formula (60)

$f(x)=\sum_{-N}^{N} c_{n}e^{inx}$ ($x$ is real).

> Let us multiply (60) by $e^{-imx}$, where $m$ is an integer; if we
>   integrate the product, (61) shows that
>
> $c_m = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)e^{-imx} dx$     (62)
>
> for $|m| \leq N$. If $|m| > N$,
>   the integral in (62) is 0.
>
> The following observation can be read off from (60) and (62): The
>   trigonometric polynomial $f$, given by (60), is real if and only if
>   $c_{-n}=\overline{c_n}$ for $n=0,\cdots, N$.

How can we easily read off?

---

Inspired by @Phicar, I come up with the proof about the inverse without introducing the concept of orthogonal:

If $f$ is real, then $c_m = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)e^{-imx} dx = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \overline{f(x)}e^{-imx} dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sum_{-N}^{N} \overline{c_{n}} e^{-i(m+n)x} dx=\frac{1}{2\pi} \sum_{-N}^{N} \overline{c_{n}}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{-i(m+n)x} dx=\overline{c_{-m}}$.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Well, $f(x)$ is real iff $\overline{f(x)}=f(x)$ but by (60)
$$\overline{f(x)}=\overline{\sum _{n=-N}^Nc_ne^{inx}}=\sum _{n=-N}^N\overline{c_ne^{inx}}= \sum _{n=-N}^N\overline{c_n}e^{-inx},$$ this last equality comes by the euler formula and the fact cosine is even and sine is odd. Now the $e^{inx}$ are orthogonal so it can only be $f(x)$ if $\overline{c_n}=c_{-n}.$ The converse is the same.

Comment: May I ask what is the use of (62)? Why Rudin mentioned it as well?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Indeed, edited. Thanks

Comment: @Tengerye Yes, it is by orthogonality.

Comment: Thanks, but the concept `orthogonal` (page 187) is introduced **after** the statement (page186). Maybe there is easier way to prove the statement? @Phicar @Kavi Rama Murthy